# error TS2339: Property 'addEnvironment' does not exist on type 'IFunction' Typescript aws-cdk

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I have an file GraphQlStack.ts, Where i am declaring my lambda function.

```
export class GraphqlStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: App, id: string, props: StackProps){
   super(scope, id, props);
   const graphqlHandler = new lambda.Function(this, "graphqlHandler", {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.GO_1_X,
      functionName: `${STAGE}-graphql`,
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(Path.join("..", "bin")),
      handler: "graphql",
      tracing: Tracing.ACTIVE,
      timeout: Duration.seconds(60),
      memorySize: 512,
      vpc: vpc,
      vpcSubnets: {
      subnets: vpc.privateSubnets,
     },
    securityGroups: [vpcSecurityGroup],
    });
    graphqlHandler.addEnvironment("DATABASE_USERNAME", DATABASE_USERNAME || "");
    graphqlHandler.addEnvironment("DATABASE_PASSWORD", DATABASE_PASSWORD || "");
  }
}
```

Above code works fine. Now,In another file S3Stack.ts where I am declaring my s3 bucket and giving above function to access s3, I want to add another environment variable.

```
export class S3Stack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: App, id: string, props: StackProps){
    super(scope, id, props);
    const bucketName = `${STAGE}-myfiles`
    const graphLambda = lambda.Function.fromFunctionAttributes(this, 'Function', {
     functionArn: `arn:aws:lambda:${CDK_DEFAULT_REGION}:${CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT}:function:${STAGE}-graphql`,
     sameEnvironment: false,
     role: lambdaRole
});
    graphLambda.addEnvironment("FILES_BUCKET_NAME", bucketName || "");
    s3Bucket.grantWrite(graphLambda);
  }
}
```

How I can add this environment variable FILES_BUCKET_NAME with existing lambda **graphLambda** ?

**Note** : Values like DATABASE_USERNAME,DATABASE_PASSWORD have been declared correctly in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CDK cannot modify imported resources. Those are just read-only references under the hood. That's why `fromFunctionAttributes` returns an `IFunction` rather than `Function`.

If this all the same app, you can just pass the lambda construct as a prop to another stack, there's no need to use imports.

Comment: This way helped me to solve the issue. Thanks